# ajax slow down with a loader gif in firefox

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox

it's my jquery ajax setup code, works well in chrome but very very slow in firefox, I found it is the loader gif caused the problem, without the loader animation, ajax runs fast in firefox, anybody konw why? thank you very much.

Javascript:

```
var div=$("<div id='mask'/>");
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend:function(jqxhr,settings){                          
        div.addClass('loader').appendTo('body');                         
    }
    ,complete:function(){
        div.remove();        
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
#mask {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    opacity:0.2;
    background-color:#fff;
}

.loader {
    background:url(ajax-loader.gif) center center no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: An animated GIF should not do this. How big is the file?

Comment: only 5kb, server-side is a php file

Answer (score 0):

First, close your div. Also, did you try to preload your GIF ? A 2.5kb cannot really slow down your ajax query... but oh, nothing's impossible. BTW, your element is #mask.

1. Create your mask element on your HTML page :

`<div id="mask"> </div>`

1. CSS it to :

> ```
> position:fixed;
> top:0;
> left:0;
> right:0;
> bottom:0;
> opacity:0.2;
> background-color:#fff;
> display : none;
> background:url(ajax-loader.gif) center center no-repeat;
> ```

1. In your javascript :

> ```
> var div = $("#mask");
> $.ajaxSetup({
>     beforeSend:function(jqxhr,settings){                          
>         div.show();                         
>     }
>     ,complete:function(){
>         div.hide();        
>     }
> });
> ```

Comment: Did you try to create an HTML element and show/hide it when processing your ajax query ? Did you check that your element is removed each time your query is done ?

Comment: yes, Michels has suggested me to do so, I just tried, but problem still exists.

Comment: thank you for your help,this is a very wired problem, I can not find a same problem online, so bad, I gave up.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that's because you add and remove the div to the body for each ajax request. I suggest you try to declare this in the html and just show/hide:

```
#mask {
 ..
 display: none;
 background:url(ajax-loader.gif) center center no-repeat;
 ..
}

$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend:function(jqxhr,settings){                          
        $('#mask').show();
    }
    ,complete:function(){
        $('#mask').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: yes, I added the div,edited code as you suggested, but ajax show no improvement, I set php max execution time to 100, so that my firefox  can complete ajax successfully. in fact, without the gif, only about 400 ms

Comment: Without the gif or without the show/hide? It seems really strange that a gif can do that. Maybe is your server side process that don't have a time fixed to return?

Comment: show/hide is good guy, gif is the suspect,I gave up finally.thank you.